# How to parse colon within string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to insert a record to an Oracle database where one field contains the path to a file, `i.e 'C:\\ProjectCodes\\ProjectZ\\ZCode.txt'`.  But when I attempt an INSERT statement I am asked about binding the value `\\ProjectCodes\\ProjectZ\\ZCode.txt`.

This is because of the colon I think.  Is it possible to parse the colon to insert this value?  The target field in the table is declared as a `varchar2`.

Here is the INSERT statement.  I am using SQL Developer.  Had to hide the IP address and password etc or I would be in trouble

```
INSERT INTO SFTP_Creds (SFTP_HOST, SFTP_PORT, SFTP_USERNAME, SFTP_PASSWORD,   
SFTP_FINGERPRINT, SFTP_HOSTKEY, SFTP_FILE)
VALUES (‘xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx’, 22, ‘CORP\\username’, ‘password’, NULL, 
NULL, 'C:\\ProjectCodes\\ProjectZ\\ZCode.txt');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code you are using for the `insert`.

Comment: What kind of field datatype?

Comment: can't see any issue here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c1dc/1

Comment: I tried your data and did not find any issue. Please post your query.

Comment: Which SQL tool do you use to run the statement?

Comment: Query posted.  I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: you have weird quotes around xxxx.xxxx. and CORP\\username I think that's what causing your issues not the C:....

Comment: @CodeBird - Thank you.  That was the problem and is now resolved.  Thats what happens when you cut and paste I suppose.

Comment: It would not hurt to execute the statement, 'set define off', prior to your dml statement.